# Moving from Spring HTTP invoker to load balanced solution

Tags: java, spring, http, tomcat, load-balancing

Our application currently uses Spring's HttpInvokerProxyFactoryBean to expose a Java service interface, with POJO requests and responses handled by our single Tomcat server.  This solution allows us to have a pure Java client and server, sharing the same Java interface.  Due to increased load, we are now looking into the possibility of load balancing across multiple Tomcat instances.

It would be nice if we could make this transition while retaining the same Java interface, as this would minimise the additional development required.  Googling seems to suggest that the most common solution for Tomcat load balancing is to use Apache http server together with mod_jk, but I presume this would mean using some communication mechanism other than Spring's HTTP invoker?  Is there a better solution which would allow us to retain more of our current code?  If not, what would be involved in transitioning between what we have now and Apache/mod_jk?

Any help would be greatly appreciated as I don't have any experience in this matter.

Comment: Why wouldn't that work with http? For the client it is still http, afaik it should still work.

Comment: My understanding is that Spring's http invoker is for Java to Java communication, so that request objects are serialized, sent via http, and deserialized on the server side.  I suppose if the Apache http server simply forwarded the same http request to a Tomcat instance, then Tomcat could still integrate with Spring and do the deserialization as it does now.  Is that possible?

Comment: It is just http traffic http is http rgardless of what is send. It remains http, so it shouldn't matter if there is an apache httpd server in front of tomcat. Have you actually tried it?